# Can you place any variable in a function, and will it remain the same function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question about homogenous differential equations, which has me scratching my head because it seems like its doing magic. The problem is as follows:

A particular solution of the differential equation $x\frac{dv}{dx}=f(v)$ has $v=2$ when $x=e$. If $k$ is the value of $v$ when $x=1$, show that $\int_k^2\frac{1}{f(y)}dy=1$.

I started by using separation of variables to get that $$\int\frac{1}{f(v)}dv=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$\int\frac{1}{f(v)}dv=\ln(x)$$
$$\int_k^2\frac{1}{f(v)}dv=\left[\ln(x)\right]_1^e=1$$

Here is when I no longer understand what am I supposed to do. Should I just say that it does not really matter which variable is being used in the function $f(x)$ because it will always be the same? I also don't really know if the question assumes that $y=vx$, as is used in v-substitution, but it was never explicitly stated.

Comment: Yes, although $v$ is a function of $x$, it can still be treated as a dummy variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably confused yourself. First step is correct but the second is not completely precise.

You cannot easily switch like that from indefinite to definite integral. When you use a substitution you have to substitute the interval as well. So this would be correct.

$$\int_k^2\frac{1}{f(v)}dv = \int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{x}dx = \left[\ln(x)\right]_1^e=1$$

You have simply used the substitution $dv=f(v)\frac{dx}{x}$.